# PHP MySql Update Multi rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hello guys I need help with the following code.

I am building a Customer Management System. What I am trying here is to update multi rows for ORDERS table => Multi rows with one click submit. Before this page I have another page i have inputs in my form:

```
<input type="text" name="qty[]" value="<?php echo $row["qty"]; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="desc[]" value="<?php echo $row["desc"]; ?>" />
<input type="text" name="price[]"value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>" />
```

When submitted the form it will go to next page that follow:

```
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){


        $qty    =  $_POST['qty'];
        $desc   = $_POST['desc'];
        $price  = $_POST['price'];
        $order  = $_POST['order'];
        $customer   = $_POST['customer'];

    $i = 0;
    $count = count($qty);

    for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
        $qty      = $qty[$i];
        $desc     = $desc[$i];
        $price    = $price[$i];


        $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `orders` SET `qty` = '".$qty."', `desc` = '".$desc."', `price` = '".$price."' WHERE `order_id` = '".$order."' ");
    }

?>
```

This code looks likes update sometimes and not, also I am getting this error for this code when I Update multi rows.

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in
```

Please help guys to solve this one.

Thanks
From Eddy

Comment: Uuurgh; `?qty[0]=1 OR 1=1; SELECT * FROM users; --`

Comment: Looks like something of `$_POST['qty']`, `$_POST['desc']` or `$_POST['price']` is string, rather than array.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php  please, please read this.

Comment: #STT LCU Do you think I should read that? I dont know how to use PDO, sorry.

Comment: @Eddy Blackpool Then you should learn it – that's why someone posted a link to the manual for you.

Comment: I dont have time to learn PDO right now I need to solve this problem. thanks

Comment: mysql_* are deprecated functions, and your code is open for SQL injection. PDO is the new library for database connections, which isn't only MySQL but almost any DB. PDO also has a better security than naked mysql_query... make a little effort, PDO is way better, and imho simpler.

Comment: #STT LCU Thanks I will check it out then later on.

Answer (score 1):

You have overwritten variables, like `$qty`.

Try this:

```
$qty    = $_POST['qty'];
$desc   = $_POST['desc'];
$price  = $_POST['price'];
$order  = $_POST['order'];
$customer   = $_POST['customer'];

$count = count($qty);

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $qty1      = $qty[$i];
    $desc1     = $desc[$i];
    $price1    = $price[$i];

    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `orders` SET `qty` = '{$qty1}', `desc` = '{$desc1}', `price` = '{$price1}' WHERE `order_id` = '{$order}';");
}
```

** I suggest use `MySQLi` or `PDO` extension instead of `MySQL`.

**UPD:**

There might be a possibility, that your `$qty`, `$desc` & `$price` may have different length. I suggest you, to modify cycle like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `orders` SET `qty` = '{$qty1}', `desc` = '{$desc1}', `price` = '{$price1}' WHERE `order_id` = '{$order}';";

$update = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_errno())echo PHP_EOL, mysql_error();
```

It might help you obtain MySQL errors.

Comment: I did the changes and nothing is updating

Comment: Strange. Everything else seems to be fine. o_0

Comment: it just not updating my database... dont know why?

Comment: Then I don`t know... It already should, unless I don`t know something that really matters.

Answer (score 0):

check value is set or not.. And use `mysqli or PDO` instead of `mysql` to avoid sql injection

```
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){

    $qty_val      = isset($qty[$i])?$qty[$i]:'';
    $desc_val     = isset($desc[$i])?$desc[$i]:'';
    $price_val    = isset($price[$i])?$price[$i]:'';


    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `orders` SET `qty` = '".$qty_val."', `desc` = '".$desc_val."', `price` = '".$price_val."' WHERE `order_id` = '".$order."' ");
}
```

Comment: The Error is gone but its not updating my fields, fields just go blank when I update them.

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach instead of for, but we assume that your arrays keep synchronized indexes:

```
 foreach ($qty as $index => $quantity_entry){
    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `orders` SET
              `qty` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($quantity_entry) . "',
              `desc` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($desc[$index]) . "',
              `price` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($price[$index]) . "'
               WHERE `order_id` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($order) . "' ");
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about non-existent indexes...
PS: notice the mysql escape - which you should never skip!

Comment: When I am updating it makes all my rows with same values="test"

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the $qty, $desc and $price variables in each iteration, so they will only work in the first one 

 

    `` $qty    =  $_POST['qty'];
    $desc   = $_POST['desc'];
    $price  = $_POST['price'];
    $order  = $_POST['order'];
    $customer   = $_POST['customer'];

$i = 0;
$count = count($qty);

for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $currentQty      = mysql_real_escape_string($qty[$i]);
    $currentDesc     = mysql_real_escape_string($desc[$i]);
    $currentPrice    = mysql_real_escape_string($price[$i]);


    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `orders` SET `qty` = '".$currentQty."', `desc` = '".$currentDesc."', `price` = '".$currentPrice."' WHERE `order_id` = '".$order."' ");
} ``

Anyway there are so much things wrong in that code. You should filter or escape your entries before sending them to mysql and all your order items will have same qty, desc and price, as you are continuously overwriting the data using the same order_id.

Comment: yea #CORRUPT already said that and I tried and still not updating

Comment: Allright, call it an update, but you are still updating multiple entries with a unique row data. If you have an array of 5 products, but you only use the order_id as the condition for the update, you will get the data from the last product in all your rows.

Comment: @EddyBlackpool Yes you do: `$qty = $qty` stores a variable to itself; you need to read from the original POST value on each iteration, instead of reading the overwritten variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assuring that all three arrays have an equal length. If one doesn't insert a price or description, the item would not get send with the request (only non-empty values are sent by a browser).

You should rework the HTML output and setup a single array with multiple key-named columns, so that you only will need to iterate over one array, instead of three.

An example would be:

```
<input type="text" name="product[0][qty]" value="QTY_1" />
<input type="text" name="product[0][desc]" value="DESC_1" />
<input type="text" name="product[0][price]"value="PRICE_1" />

<input type="text" name="product[1][qty]" value="QTY_2" />
<input type="text" name="product[1][desc]" value="DESC_2" />
<input type="text" name="product[1][price]"value="PRICE_2" />
```

Iterate over the products array with `foreach` and additionally check, whether the columns are set:

```
foreach( $_POST['product'] as $inputRow )
{
    if( !isset( $inputRow['qty'] ) || !isset( $inputRow['desc'] ) || !isset( $inputRow['price'] ) )
    {
        echo 'Some input is missing; can\'t store to database';
        continue;
    }

    /* insert to DB here, but please use prepared statement or at least escape the user inputs properly! */
}
```

Comment: So you want me to use Loop for my inputs?

Comment: @EddyBlackpool Yes – as you already use loops for your inputs!?